# I need to divide very large numbers in java without using any external libraries (Homework)

Tags: java

I need to be able to do 1938757289258398239399949292934/14583949053930202 without using any external java functions or libraries. I have each digit of my numbers stored in a linked list. What else can I do?

Can someone help me divide an algorithm. I've been trying at it for a few hours now and i'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: Does `BigInteger` count as "external"?

Comment: This is just long division using two lists of digits in a computer instead of two lists of digits written on paper.

Comment: Assuming subtraction, you can do [digital division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28digital%29).

Answer (score 4):

"External" Java libraries?  (BigInteger is built-in, if you can use that.)

Otherwise, the simplest approach to division is probably binary, as follows.  You know that `log(a/b) = log(a) - log(b)`, so you have an estimate on the number of bits in the result.  Let `r` be the result.  In pseudocode,

```
for i = the most significant bit the result could have, iterating down to 0
  if (r + 2^i) * b <= a
    r += 2^i
```